# Trouble getting gdal2xyz to convert a file

Tags: gdal, gdal2xyz

I am using gdal2xyz for the first time, because it is able to convert a geoTIF to xyz and use multiple bands while converting (in my case, I have an image with 3 bands I need to convert to xyz).

I have found documentation on gdal2xyz  [at this location](https://gdal.org/programs/gdal2xyz.html).

In the documentation, it shows example usage about the below code, and states "To create a text file in xyz format from the input file input.tif, including the first and second bands, while replacing the dataset nodata values with zeros." - This is exactly what I need (except I need 3 bands). So I ran their example :

```
gdal2xyz -b 1 -b 2 -dstnodata 0 input.tif output.txt
```

And I get the following error with no resulting output :

> "Usage: gdal2xyz.py [-skip factor] [-srcwin xoff yoff width height]
> [-band b] srcfile [dstfile]"

Since I am literally copy/pasting their script, I don't understand what I am doing wrong.

In case anyone were to assist, I  [uploaded my geoTIF here to my Google Drive (public link) - it is just over 2.MB.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Mwjw1XxNwpffgQaikHLZ6YgKv6EAeHTk/view?usp=sharing)

In case it matters, I grabbed the python source code  [at this link](https://github.com/postmates/gdal/blob/master/scripts/gdal2xyz.py) .

I hope I can get this resolved, because I have no idea what to do. In any variation of the script, I get that same warning telling me about usage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are reading the [documentation](https://gdal.org/programs/gdal2xyz.html) for a [newer version](https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/commit/e393c7cc5f98fe8ab16d1a1f4de5927d1f3afb3f) of gdal2xyz than you are using.  You copied the `gdal2xyz.py` script from an ancient version of GDAL (1.7.1 released 2010) in a fork/copy not owned by the GDAL project.

Your version only supports the arguments:

```
gdal2xyz.py [-skip factor] [-srcwin xoff yoff width height]
            [-band b] [-csv] srcfile [dstfile]
```

Note there's no `-b` or `-dstnodata` arguments.  So use:

```
gdal2xyz.py -band 1 -band 2 input.tif output.txt
```